# Corruption, Bribery and Greed

Tags: ethics

Why do humans tend to lean towards corruption, bribery and greed?

Comment: Please abstain from any discriminatory or opinionated content in both answers *and* questions. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.standardmedia.co.ke/article/2000193065/survey-kenya-ranked-third-most-corrupt-country-in-the-world

Comment: And its not opinionated content its from various reports from media outlets

Comment: You write about Africa, especially Kenya, and link to a PWC report that does clearly state that *France and South Africa* are faring worse, still insisting that your discription is neither discriminatory nor opinionated? Are you serious?

Comment: We can argue all day over opinions on whether or not africa or kenya or even 3/4 of the world are corrupt. But we should atleast try and be human to the rest of those who can't access power and fend for themselves

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. If you would like, here is a link to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the development of man different stages of enlightenment occur. Simplified these stages can be put into four categories:

1. The understanding of the power in power itself. Power being defined as: control of things given a value: money, weapons, technology and sow on.
2. The understanding of developing power, creating new technology, building a financial system. Here power is still defined as above.
3. The understanding of power as a unity. Now the definition of power changes: It is not only what I, the man, have, it is what I and them I'm united with, have.
4. The understanding that power is merely made up. Money is just paper given a value. It is made by man because man is greedy for power.

Eksampels:

1. By acquiring more goods, by possessing objects (objects: everything manmade), you have trading goods, the ability not to starve and can now cover your basic needs.
2. By using time and effort you can develop your ability of acquiring, get better at collecting data, barriers or whatever, end though this realize what you are good at and on which fields you are lacking knowledge. How can your system be developed?
3. Now, you, from step 2 being as developed as you can be, other inputs is needed to further develop. to further gain power. You group in big companies, states, families anything that can gain you power. Though knowledge, politics or even strength.
4. You now realize that power has no limit, and the whole powerplay is created in fear of lacking power.  It is mounted in angst (danish word created by Kirkegård eng:Kirkegaard). It is only by acknowledging that power, as defined in the first category, is nothing more than a piece of paper created out off angst. Rise above angst and you will have true power.

In summery: People that are greedy are the ones who are left on the 1. perhaps 2. step. They are not jet understanding the power in unity and they are far from understanding the indifference of traditional power. This is why greed, bribery and corruption exist. It comes from failure to realize what power is.

Your question should have been: "What is power?" this is interesting!

One note: The above is simplyfied, to cover more read Kirkegaard, Enten/eller (eng: Either/or). Great book, best in danish!

Answer (score 0):

Human nature and environment dictates such activities. It's in every society and human being to some degree. Some act on the choice others refrain. The more corrupt choices to affiliate with, the more it grows and becomes epidemic in nature like disease. People have an ornate desire for it. Unfortunately it will be all of humanities downfall. To curve or extinguish it, requires lack of freedoms. So in the end corruption still wins by caging us into a police state. Sad reality for us all. No privacy by corruption in order to stop it. Police it! Until everything is lost. Also usually in my studies it calls itself a perceived good to curve itself from being stopped! Corruption is truly sinister activities.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Please take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) and keep in mind that we look for objective, ideally referenced answers here, not your (or anyone else's) contemplation on a subject matter. See [this meta post](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers).

Comment: But human behaviour does influence philosophy or does it not